# Programmatically autoscroll multiple virtual viewports – Angular Material CDK

Tags: angular, angular-material

It is a simple task in Angular to make a Material CDK Scrolling list automatically scroll to a certain point. What I cannot figure out, however, is how to make two or more lists automatically scroll. Only the first list in the HTML code performs the autoscroll.

My HTML:

```
<button (click)="onButtonClick()">Scroll to end</button>

<div class="container">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400"
                              class="example-viewport">
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" minBufferPx="200" maxBufferPx="400"
                              class="example-viewport">
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

My Typescript:

```
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

/** @title Fixed size virtual scroll with custom buffer parameters */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CdkVirtualScrollFixedBufferExample {
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
  items = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);

  onButtonClick() {
    this.viewPort.scrollToIndex(100, 'smooth');
  }
}
```

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-programatically-scroll-bbudel?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.ts). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is change `@ViewChild` to `@ViewChildren`, and you will have to use `QueryList` too:

```
@ViewChildren(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewPorts: QueryList<CdkVirtualScrollViewport>;
  
onButtonClick() {
    console.log(this.viewPorts.toArray());
    this.viewPorts.toArray().forEach(el => el.scrollToIndex(100, "smooth"));
}
```

Now no matter how many CdkVirtualScrollViewport they will all scroll to index 100.

Here is a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-programatically-scroll-4smabf?file=app/cdk-virtual-scroll-fixed-buffer-example.ts) on stackblitz.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!